# Need a batch command to create a karaoke automatically

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg

I used these codes to create a karaoke and burn it to VCD.

`xxxxxx_1.m4a` file is left channel (instrumental),
`xxxxxx_0.m4a` file is right channel (song with vocal).
Combine them to `become xxxxxx.m4a`.

```
ffmpeg -i 123456_1.m4a -i 123456_0.m4a -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c1|c1<c2+c3[aout]" -map "[aout]" 123456.m4a
```

`xxxxxx_3.mp4` file is a video without sound.
Combine `xxxxxx_3.mp4` with `xxxxxx.m4a` to become karaoke video.

```
ffmpeg -i 123456_3.mp4 -i 123456.m4a -c:v copy -c:a copy 123456.mp4
```

Convert the `xxxxxx.mp4` to `.mpg` format and burn to VCD.

```
ffmpeg -i 123456.mp4 -target pal-vcd 123456.mpg
```

All these `123456_1.m4a`, `123456_0.m4a` and `123456_3.mp4` are in the same folder.
This is only 1 song. I have a lot of songs that need to be converted and I don't want to copy and paste every song to perform this task.

I tried the `for /f` command to automate this conversion without success.

Comment: See `set /?` for substring operations. You need to use `For` without the `/f` switch. See `For /?`. Also you can use parts of a path by qualifying the variable with `~`. So `%~dpn0` is the path without the extension of the batch file. Ditto the for command - `%%~dpnA`. See `for /?` and `call /?`.

Comment: Normally the `for /f` would be the way to go. Could you add what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (untested):

```
@Echo off
Set "Base=X:\path\to\your\folder"
PushD "%Base%"2>Nul ||(Echo Can't change to %Base% &Pause&Exit /B 1)
For %%A in (*_3.mp4) Do For /f "Delims=_" %%B in ("%%A") Do Call :Assemble "%%~A" "%%~B"
PopD
Goto :Eof
:Assemble
Echo Processing %~2
If Not Exist "%~2_0.m4a" (Echo %~2 right channel missing& Goto :Eof)
If Not Exist "%~2_1.m4a" (Echo %~2 left  channel missing& Goto :Eof)
ffmpeg -i "%~2_1.m4a" -i "%~2_0.m4a" -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c1|c1<c2+c3[aout]" -map "[aout]" "%~2.m4a"
ffmpeg -i %1 -i "%~2.m4a" -c:v copy -c:a copy "%~2.mp4"
ffmpeg -i "%~2.mp4" -target pal-vcd "%~2.mpg"
```

Comment: Just to add `2>Nul` before the double pipe on line 3. You're coding it for a possible error but not redirecting that error message, which would be okay if you weren't then including your own error message.

Comment: @Compo Agreed and changed. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thanks for the codes. I will test it and let you know the outcome.

Comment: I added <c0+c1|c1<c2+c3[aout]" -map "[aout]" "%~2.m4a" at the end of line 12. The codes worked perfectly. Thanks you very much for all your help. 8-)

Comment: @RayLooi That part got lost somehow, thanks for the edit.